# Angular - loop over nested javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I use `ng-repeat` to loop over data that contains many nested array data?

I have data that will have many "Segments"

Example:

```
confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[0].FlightNumber
confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[1].FlightNumber
confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[2].FlightNumber
```

I have done both `ng-repeat` with angular, and without angular I would end up resorting to javascript that loops over data and creates the html dynamically,  *but I wish to do this the ANGULAR way..  HOW?*

**HTML with Angular/Javascript Arrays**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Flight</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Departs</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Arrives</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[0].FlightNumber}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          ({{confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[0].DepartureAirport}})
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ({{confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[0].ArrivalAirport}})  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, so you can use nested ng-repeat...

Comment: example?    also i was looking into angular.forEach     , is that an option ?

Comment: angular.foreach is very similar to javascript native foreach it just iterates over array, but that offers compatibility across browsers

Comment: Any decent examples of what I want to do?  seems that forEach is going to be on controller etc...  so perhaps I do want to use nested ng-repeat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested *ng-repeat* to bind your data - see a demo below:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.confirm = {
    booking: {
      flightData: [{
        Segments: [{
          FlightNumber: 1
        }, {
          FlightNumber: 2
        }]
      }, {
        Segments: [{
          FlightNumber: 3
        }, {
          FlightNumber: 4
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
  // console.log($scope.confirm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in confirm.booking.flightData">
    Data {{$index + 1}}:
    <div ng-repeat="y in x.Segments">
      <div>Flight No: {{y.FlightNumber}}</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to display only the following:

```
confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[0].FlightNumber
confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[1].FlightNumber
confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments[2].FlightNumber
```

then you can use [`limitTo`](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_limitto.asp) - see demo below:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.confirm = {
    booking: {
      flightData: [{
        Segments: [{
          FlightNumber: 1
        }, {
          FlightNumber: 2
        }]
      }, {
        Segments: [{
          FlightNumber: 3
        }, {
          FlightNumber: 4
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
  // console.log($scope.confirm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in confirm.booking.flightData | limitTo : 1">
    Data {{$index + 1}}:
    <div ng-repeat="y in x.Segments">
      <div>Flight No: {{y.FlightNumber}}</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is  `    Data {{$index + 1}}:`   and should I be concerned with performance ... and can I use a track by to get more speed?

Comment: `$index` gets you the index of the array that is in `ng-repeat`... `trackBy` is needed if there are duplicate elements in your array...

Comment: @kukkuz is needed if there are duplicate elements in your array and you dont need them

Comment: @kukkuz   -  How have been a big help. Thanks for not insulting me and being just a fantastic person!   cheers!

Comment: last comment based on my experience with some people on SO,  not on this question and answers just to be clear.   thx

Answer (score 1):

Nesting can be done in repeats, but repeating too much in ng-repeats can be costly in terms of performance as angular creates scopes for each element repeated. Hence, filtering data till the perfect abstracted values that you need in terms of html should be done in the js file.

For eg: if u need only segements in the html form do this, or if u need even flight data in html form follow @Rachel's post

```
<ul data-ng-repeat="item in confirm.booking.flightData[0].Segments">
    <li>{{ item.FlightNumber}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data is in `flightdetails`, then you can go about it like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="a in flightdetails ">
        <div  ng-repeat="b in a.booking">
          <div  ng-repeat="c in b.flightdata">
           <div  ng-repeat="d in c.segments">
                 {{d.flightnumber}}
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example here:

http://codepen.io/ackzell/pen/ENBymo

It ultimately looks like this, but check the pen as it has some more info:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="flight in vm.flightData">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="segment in flight.Segments">
        <em>FlightNumber</em> {{ segment.FlightNumber }}
        <br />
        <em>Departure:</em> {{ segment.DepartureAirport }}
        <br />
        <em>Arrival:</em> {{ segment.ArrivalAirport }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Nesting ng-repeats would help, but maybe you want to give your data some treatment first.